# paramiko.SSHException: Channel closed

Tags: python, paramiko

I try to use python 2.7.1 and paramiko 1.12.0:

```
connection = paramiko.SSHClient()
connection.load_host_keys(os.path.expanduser(os.path.join("~", ".ssh", "known_hosts")))
connection.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())

connection.connect(hostIP, 22, 'd', 'd')

command = 'ls'
(stdin, stdout, stderr) = connection.exec_command(command)
response = stdout.readlines()
errormsg = stderr.read()
```

But I get this error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):<br>
  File "./ssh.py", line 32, in <module><br>
    (stdin, stdout, stderr) = connection.exec_command(command)<br>
  File "/app/python/2.7.1/LMWP3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paramiko/client.py", line 379, in exec_command<br>
    chan.exec_command(command)<br>
  File "/app/python/2.7.1/LMWP3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paramiko/channel.py", line 218, in exec_command<br>
    self._wait_for_event()<br>
  File "/app/python/2.7.1/LMWP3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paramiko/channel.py", line 1129, in _wait_for_event<br>
    raise e<br>
paramiko.SSHException: Channel closed.
```

Comment: Your syntax of connect is incorrect. You should search google first for sample codes.

Comment: What do you mean? Regarding the sample codes that's right as I see.

Comment: I have tied the 
    connection.connect(hostIP, username='d', password='d')
version as well.

Comment: `connection.load_host_keys(os.path.expanduser(os.path.join("~", ".ssh", "known_hosts")))` I dont think you need this line. You can remove it and try

Comment: I have already tried it so as well.

Comment: Try with root username/password, And also are you able to connect properly with ssh manually.

Answer (score 1):

```
import paramiko
s = paramiko.SSHClient()
s.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
conn = s.connect(hostIP, username ='root', password='rootpassword', port=22)

command = 'pwd'
(stdin, stdout, stderr) = s.exec_command(command)

print stdout.read()
s.close()
```

This should work fine with root user on linux. If it's not, you are probably passing wrong values for hostIP (for ex: quotes in the value), username, password.